# How to restart a function, when the data it operating on it is updated

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, callback, kotlin-coroutines

Inside the `onCreateView()` method of a fragment, I am attaching 3 `valueEventListener`s to different, mutually exclusive locations at firebase databse. Whenever the data at the reference is updated, they are triggered asynchronously. My sample code looks like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    listner1 = ref1.addCustomValueEventListener {
        list1.clear()
        // do some operation and populate list1
        rewriteMainData()
    }
    listner2 = ref2.addCustomValueEventListener {
        list2.clear()
        // do some operation and populate list2
        rewriteMainData()
    }
    listner3 = ref3.addCustomValueEventListener {
        list3.clear()
        // do some operation and populate list3
        rewriteMainData()
    }
}

private fun rewriteMainData() {
    mainList.clear()
    mainDbReference.addCustomListenerForSingleValueEvent {
        // compare the values present here with values in list1, list2, list3
        // populate mainList with appropriate values
        // notifyAdapterDataSetChanged
    }
    return
}

// EXTENSION FUNCTION
internal inline fun DatabaseReference.addCustomValueEventListener(crossinline onDataChange: (DataSnapshot) -> Unit) =
addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        onDataChange(snapshot)
    }
    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled: ", error.toException())
    }
})
```

In this example however, if one listener is triggered soon after the another, then `rewriteMainData()` will be invoked twice. At that time, `mainList` will be wrote simultaneously by two callbacks. One way to solve this is to use an instance of `ReentrantLock` to avoid simultaneous writes. But this makes latest invoke to wait till its previous invoke is completed, which is redundant since all data will be cleared and rewritten.
Hence is there any way to know when `rewriteMainData()` is invoked and if it is already running, then to just abort and restart the function with updated lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [yield](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/yield.html), every time before doing any intensive work to check for cancellation of the current coroutine.

```kotlin
// instance variable on the class
var job1: Job? = null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    ref1.addCustomValueEventListener {
        job1?.cancel()
        job2?.cancel()
        job3?.cancel()

        job1 = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            list1.clear()
    
            // do some operation and populate list1
            rewriteMainData()
        }
    }
    // ...
}


private suspend fun rewriteMainData() {
    mainList.clear()

    // before every intensive work, to check for cancellation.
    yield()
    // some work involving cpu consumption or takes significant time.
}
```

Note that, the impact of this is quite small or even worse if the work is just to update the list synchronously, which involves just a few CPU cycles and millisecond of time. Use this only if you are sure there is a performance impact due to the work `rewriteMainData` is doing in your current code.

Comment: For now, all I have is calling a single value event on another database reference and comparing those values with list1,2,3 and writing appropriate values to mainList and then notifyingAdapterDataSetChanged. So as you mentioned, I think its good to let it be as it is. But thanks for this answer, might come for big help in future.

Answer (score 1):

> mainList will be wrote simultaneously by two callbacks.

That's not possible with the code you have here.  Database callbacks are invoked on the Android main thread by default, which means that they cannot be invoked simultaneously.  They will be invoked sequentially.  As such, you don't have to worry about threading or locking.

Comment: If I understood properly, He actually wants to dismantle any work done on the response to the old event if new event has arrived and old function is still executing (considering it somewhat intensive and unrelated work). The IO may be done in different thread and then posted to the Main for the invocation, but still another IO thread maybe is waiting for the event to be consumed.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu I don't see any I/O or anything asynchronous in the code.  It is all synchronous, except for the database listeners, which will be invoked on the main thread sequentially.

Comment: If it is called then that's good. But still, if the database values are updated in the middle of running of `rewriteMainData()` function, then continuing with old data in that function is of no use. So is there a way to abort current run, and rerun with updated values?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  The listeners are reactive and will reflect the current state of the database as it changes over time.  Locking things will not change or help that behavior at all - locking on the main thread can only hurt.  If something here is not working the way you expect, then please ask a new question explaining what that is.

Comment: @DougStevenson `rewriteMainData()` involves calling a single value event on another database reference and comparing those values with list1,2,3 and writing appropriate values to mainList and then notifyingAdapterDataSetChanged.

Comment: Then just add a single listener on mainDbReference to always know the current value instead of having to query it again each time.  This will be far more convenient.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yeah, I forgot I can do that way! This is my first complete android project, hence so many confusions. Btw, is an instanceof `DataSnapshot` is light to be stored? or does it consume too much memory?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately along with your specific concerns about what you're trying to do with the snapshot.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65205301/how-to-handle-race-conditions-in-kotlin-when-listening-to-a-firebase-database-n), around the same issue. Just check once.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ohh.. So you are the one who wrote that blog I mentioned in my recent question. Few days ago, I had just chanced upon that post and today it helped me to avoid hours of debugging. Thanks a lot for that blog. I didn't got comment section in that blog. So commenting here.