# How to handle race conditions in kotlin, when listening to a firebase database node

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, race-condition, kotlin-coroutines

Today, when I was working on my android project, I saw this weird behavior of my app. When I click on an icon and move to a different activity, which would basically insert another child into the node to which first activity was listening to. But to my surprise, when return back, everything in the screen was doubled. When I refresh the view, it again would become normal. I repeated it many times, thinking it may be a glitch. But same result every time. When I look into database, new child was never created.
[image: Glitch image]

This is my code for listener. (doOnDataChange is an extension function, I defined for onValueEventListener)

```
val chats = mutableListOf<Chat>()
chatsListener = dbChatsReference.orderByChild(NODE_LAST_MESSAGE_TIME).doOnDataChange { it ->
    chats.clear()
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch(IO) {
        // some IO work
        for (ss in it.children) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: ${ss.key!!} , ${Thread.currentThread()}")
            // populate chats with appropriate data
        }
    }
}
```

Then I logged what's happening.

```
2020-12-08 23:52:39.721 4114-4200/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: cleared
2020-12-08 23:52:40.043 4114-4200/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: cleared
2020-12-08 23:52:40.132 4114-4200/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: j7ZmBA650WVmvd9z6BsN7UsvPlJ2VtDh2KtpeDhwXN386b580Lpr6dj2 , Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]
2020-12-08 23:52:40.133 4114-4200/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: lIq43hHgzKfsE0zbYIeiH4dhswT2KQTXik3LjYMriCOdPoTKLNAtoVf2 , Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]
2020-12-08 23:52:40.139 4114-4200/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: lIq43hHgzKfsE0zbYIeiH4dhswT2MWUYn8kW4MPlZvnn420XrN4p5kq2 , Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]
2020-12-08 23:52:40.140 4114-4201/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: j7ZmBA650WVmvd9z6BsN7UsvPlJ2VtDh2KtpeDhwXN386b580Lpr6dj2 , Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-3,5,main]
2020-12-08 23:52:40.141 4114-4201/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: lIq43hHgzKfsE0zbYIeiH4dhswT2KQTXik3LjYMriCOdPoTKLNAtoVf2 , Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-3,5,main]
2020-12-08 23:52:40.143 4114-4200/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: lIq43hHgzKfsE0zbYIeiH4dhswT2VtDh2KtpeDhwXN386b580Lpr6dj2 , Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]
2020-12-08 23:52:40.145 4114-4201/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: lIq43hHgzKfsE0zbYIeiH4dhswT2MWUYn8kW4MPlZvnn420XrN4p5kq2 , Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-3,5,main]
2020-12-08 23:52:40.146 4114-4200/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: lIq43hHgzKfsE0zbYIeiH4dhswT2j7ZmBA650WVmvd9z6BsN7UsvPlJ2 , Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]
2020-12-08 23:52:40.148 4114-4201/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: lIq43hHgzKfsE0zbYIeiH4dhswT2VtDh2KtpeDhwXN386b580Lpr6dj2 , Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-3,5,main]
2020-12-08 23:52:40.150 4114-4200/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: -MO2_oyUjEV55HAGlzXN , Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]
2020-12-08 23:52:40.152 4114-4201/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: lIq43hHgzKfsE0zbYIeiH4dhswT2j7ZmBA650WVmvd9z6BsN7UsvPlJ2 , Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-3,5,main]
2020-12-08 23:52:45.395 4114-4114/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onCreateView: 
2020-12-08 23:52:45.842 4114-4200/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: cleared
2020-12-08 23:52:46.263 4114-4200/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: j7ZmBA650WVmvd9z6BsN7UsvPlJ2VtDh2KtpeDhwXN386b580Lpr6dj2 , Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]
2020-12-08 23:52:46.264 4114-4200/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: lIq43hHgzKfsE0zbYIeiH4dhswT2KQTXik3LjYMriCOdPoTKLNAtoVf2 , Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]
2020-12-08 23:52:46.268 4114-4200/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: lIq43hHgzKfsE0zbYIeiH4dhswT2MWUYn8kW4MPlZvnn420XrN4p5kq2 , Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]
2020-12-08 23:52:46.273 4114-4200/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: lIq43hHgzKfsE0zbYIeiH4dhswT2VtDh2KtpeDhwXN386b580Lpr6dj2 , Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]
2020-12-08 23:52:46.278 4114-4200/com.skb.skara D/ChatsFragment: onDataChange: lIq43hHgzKfsE0zbYIeiH4dhswT2j7ZmBA650WVmvd9z6BsN7UsvPlJ2 , Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]
```

Then I remembered, as mentioned in this [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/what-happens-to-database-listeners-when-security-rules-reject-an-update.html), when you make some changes to database, immediately listeners are triggered, without actually waiting for the write to complete. Afterwards, if the write fails, the listeners are triggered again with the old values to nullify the previous trigger. Since I have used coroutines here, chats list is being updated simultaneously by two threads. This can happen even when two changes are made to the node with very short delay in between.

So can someone tell me how to overcome this race condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using mutable lists and data classes, but rather just use `map` on your data to transform it to a read-only List of the type you need for your list view.

Make your RecyclerView.Adapter store a `var` property so it is changed all at once. Change the data list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Then it is only ever looking at one list at a time.

Comment: Should I do this here, in order to avoid race conditions, or should I start following this everywhere in my project? I mean which is the good practice or standard practice.

Comment: It's not critical in all cases. Part of the problem might be how you're switching dispatchers. If you knew your mutable list could only ever be modified by the same thread, you wouldn't have to worry about other threads manipulating it concurrently. I never launch coroutines into the IO dispatcher. I only wrap the IO code in `withContext(IO){}` and work with  UI related stuff exclusively in the Main thread.

Comment: Oh yeah.. First I have to go through the entire project to make changes you said already. Then I will come back here later.

Comment: Actually, in the code mentioned above, I have IO intensive works inside the for loops also. So even if I the code on main thread and only do that particular IO task using withContext{}IO, then also I will get the same result. Only thing that changes is, now instead of two threads, from inside a single thread, two coroutines get intertwined and still update chats list asynchronously.

Comment: Either use read only lists like I answered above or use mutexes to enforce only one thread working with the list and/or property at a time.

Comment: I don't know what is mutex (I will check it). How about `job.cancel()`

Comment: `job.cancel()` wouldn't be a reliable way to resolve this. It doesn't instantly stop whatever a coroutine is doing. It only stops it when it reaches its next suspend point.

Comment: For me, `job.cancel` worked. Also I have suspension point on every run of for loop.

Comment: Concurrency problems are difficult to test thoroughly, because they can happen very rarely. If one coroutine cancels the other one when the other one is already in the process of iterating a loop (which includes internal iterations like `clear()`), then it can start iterating the loop while the other cancelled job hasn't yet reached its next suspension point. Even if you suspend in every iteration, then you are just hoping that the current iteration completes before the next line of code runs, which is just flipping a coin.

Comment: Got you :) Thanks. I will go through mutexes. If I use read only lists and replace old list with new list then I think I have to recreate whole adapter itself, if so, then its costly.

Comment: You won't have to replace the adapter. You can just pass a new list to it and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. It's true a mutable list will perform better, depending on the length of the data. Mutexes aren't hard to use, so that may be your best option.